# Nokia Series 40 application to take a photo

Tags: java-me, nokia, flashlite, series-40

I am looking to have a Symbian [Series 40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_40) application to take a photo using the onboard camera every 5 minutes and then upload the image to a server via GPRS.

Is this possible? I need to know whether this is possible before going deeper into it. Would [S60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S60_%28software_platform%29) be better?

Comment: S40 is not Symbian based, so you cannot use Symbian applications.

Comment: It should be possible with JaveME. Use JSR-135 API to take the picture and then upload it using HTTP. JSR-135 should be supported in all modern S40 devices.

Note that S40 is a software platform used on a series of Nokia devices. S40 is not Symbian based, there is no such thing as Symbian S40.
---------------

thanks for you comment. One question though, how do i get the S40 app into my mobile phone?

Comment: Bluetooth? Download from webpage? USB cable? Email? 
S40 apps are j2me midlets. There is plenty of documentation on how to develop, package and deploy j2me midlets on the web. Try forum.nokia.com for instance.

Comment: Great question, except S40 are not Symbian as Ola pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly corrected version of the code linked by Mihir (it had an obvious bug and another bug which is probably an interoperability issue) which works on my Nokia 3110 classic: [Java ME Image Capture Example](http://pastebin.com/LAdDEwb6)